# OpenCV VideoCapture() in Python on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to use `cv2.VideoCapture()` on a MacBook in Python to read an *.avi video. but it is not working.

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture('filename.avi')
vid.grab() # This gives me false.
```

also when I try to count the number of frames I usually get `0.0`. However, when I use `vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` then `vid.grab()` I get `True`, I tried to figure out why I am getting this issue but with no luck.

On the other hand I tried using the `Imageio` module and used `vid =imageio.get-reader('filename.avi')` then counted the number of frames and I got `32` the correct results. However, I can't use Imageio because I want to the OpenCV Adaptive_Thresholding function and this function requires 8-bits 1-Channel and the output when using `imageio` is not, so, I get an error.

Does anyone know how to solve/work around this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use ```ret, frame = vid.read()```?

Comment: Yes, `ret` is  False and `frame` doesn't give me anything.

Comment: Have you tried to put abosolute path, i.e., `/your/path/to/filename.avi` instead of `filename.avi`?